# Debian Shell Bash Script - Delete old backups/directorys

Tags: bash, shell, debian, backup

I have a small script which is creating a backup every 2 hours. Now I would like to delete the old ones. I know "find" can do this, but I want it more advanced.

I want to keep

- all backups form the last 24 hours
- 4 backups from the last 5 days
- 1 backup from the last 14 days
- everything older than 14 days can be deleted

Could you tell me how to do this via. a shell bash script in debian ?
I couldn´t find anything for this via. google.

Thank You.

Comment: Your main problem is "selection" but not "deletion". And you should first list all the backups with creation time and then select reserved ones according to your rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not reinvent the wheel. Take a look at [rsnapshot](http://www.rsnapshot.org/). Unless you want to use this as a learning exercise, I see no reason why you would want to spend the time that has already been spent to solve this problem.

Comment: I have a java application which executes the backup.sh, I don´t want to make it more complicated with adding another program. Yes, It is more outlay for me now, but as soon as it is working it is just copy and paste. No need for installing extra programms.

Comment: You are basically asking people to write code for you for free. Rsnapshot already does exactly what you want in a more sophisticated way than you could ever achieve with a bash script, and nothing is stopping you from running `rsnapshot` from your java program.

Comment: mhh, I don´t want you to write the code for me. I just thought I could get an example or link which shows how to this.

Comment: Of course the code can be written, but there are many details and special cases and ways to accidentally delete the wrong things and it is not worthwhile to go through that trouble when code to solve this very same problem already exists.

Comment: Ok, can I tell rsnapshot to run commands before the backup starts ?
The first command 60 seconds before it starts the second 5 seconds and one command as it starts ?
And is rsnapshot able to dump mysql databases which should be backuped, too ? I also need to run two commands when the backup is finished.

Comment: You can use rsnapshot as a subroutine to whatever complex stuff you want to do. And you can dump the mysql database first, then backup will proceed normally.

Comment: and how can I run a command when it is finished ? does it tell the script which runs it, when it is finished ?

Comment: In the same way that you can run a command after any arbitrary process finishes?

Comment: You either run it synchronously, or not. What I am suggesting is that you substitute the part of your script which is intended to do the backup, with a call to `rsnapshot`. Nothing else has to change in your original setup.

Comment: I just read the instruction, they only talk from crontab. Does it also work if I run it via. a bash script which doesn´t run every 2 hours ? It only runs every 2 hours in the peak times.

Comment: From the manual: 

" rsnapshot will typically be invoked as root by a cron job, or series of cron jobs. It is possible, however
, to run as any arbitrary user
       with an alternate configuration file."

You can just invoke the command yourself  (or your java/bash program). I can't really give you a tutorial on rsnapshot, but the information is there, and a simple configuration should solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, I could use it, but I have one big problem. An daily and hourly can run at the same time. Lets say I manage the daily and weekly via. crontab and the hourly via. a java application. The daily runs at the moment, when the java starts the hourly. Now the daily is corrupted because the hourly backup changes files which the daily uses. Any idea what I could do ? There is no queue from rsnapshot.

Comment: Rsnapshot by default uses a lock which prevents two invocations from running simultaneously, look in the man page for `lockfile`.

Comment: ahh, thanks. So when the file is locked, it will cancle the backup or queue it ?

Comment: All the information is detailed in the man page. "If a lockfile exists when rsnapshot starts, it will try to read the file and stop with an error if it can't.". If you're afraid of these collisions, there are a couple of things you could do: 
1) In cron, you can specify the time at which scripts are run, so you can set, eg  the hourly snapshot at 00m, and daily at 20m.
2) You can wrap rsnapshot in a simple script (bash, whatever) that will keep trying until the lock file is acquired.

Comment: Ok thanks. Sry if I rob your time, but I´m a total noob on this topic. I can´t use the first way, because the hourly snapshout doesn´t run via. crontab at a fixed time/interval. Could you tell me how a bash script would look like, which checks the lockfile ? I could only find tutorial on how to create a lockfile and not how to check them pause and try again.

Comment: while true; do rsnapshot -c /path/to/my/config/file hourly && break; echo "rsnapshot failed, trying again in 30 seconds"; sleep 30; done;
echo "rsnapshot succeeded"

Comment: Of course, this just assumes that rsnapshot failed because it could not lock the file, but it could really fail for any number of reasons. If you need a more rigorous solution, you should check the output of the command.

Comment: No problem, glad this was of help

Comment: sry if I have to disturb you again. I got a new problem. I have multiple java applications running and they can´t backup to the same time. So I have to split it. Is it possible with rsnapshot to have like two configs. The alpha backups to the alpha directory ever 2 hours and the beta to the beta directory every two hours from the same unix user ?

Comment: got it, I can run another config file as you did in your loop example

Comment: But one more thing. If I want to do a backup from the backup, I would need to create these lock file myself. 1. Does rsnapshot use the same lockfile for "rsnapshot sync" and "rsnapshot hourly" ? 2. how can I create a lockfile that rsnapshot likes. When I look into the lockfile from rsnapshot, it has the pid of the process inside, how can I create one with the pid of my script inside, couldn´t find anything with pid and shell script on google ?

Comment: Didn't notice your comment. The man page tells you how to specify a lockfile to use, and explains the behaviour of the program regarding it. You want to look at an option "stop on stale lockfile", I can not remember the exact name. Please make sure to read the man page, all of your questions can be answered there.